# How to properly set Headers in JavaScript. Receiving SyntaxError and Cross-Origin Request blocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching data from an API and I'm receiving the following errors.

When I remove the header which worked fine up until a day ago, I get:

> Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

When I add the header, I receive:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpA4x.jpg)

I've searched around and got a rough idea how to handle the CORS error, but then I received the JSON error and was thrown off. Is there something I'm missing or is my header set up incorrectly?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { TopAnime } from './TopAnime';



class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    topTv: [],
    topAiring: [],
    topUpcoming: []
  }


  async getData() {
    const api = fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v3', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });

    // const api = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3";
    const urls = [
      `${api}/top/anime/1`,
      `${api}/top/anime/1/tv`,
      `${api}/top/anime/1/airing`,
      `${api}/top/anime/1/upcoming`,
    ];

    return Promise.all(
      urls.map(async url => {
        return await fetch(url); // fetch data from urls
      })
    )
      .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map(resp => resp.json())) // turn data into JSON
        .then(data => {
          const topTvFiltered = data[0].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 6) // filter out top 6 
          const topAiringFiltered = data[1].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 6)
          const topUpcomingFiltered = data[2].top.filter(item => item.rank <= 6)

          this.setState({
            topTv: topTvFiltered,
            topAiring: topAiringFiltered,
            topUpcoming: topUpcomingFiltered
          });
          console.log(data)
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log("There was an error:" + err))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    const { topTv, topAiring, topUpcoming } = this.state
    return (
      <HomeWrapper>
        <h2>Top TV</h2>
        <TopAni>
          {/* {topTv.length > 0 ? <h2>Top TV</h2> : null} */}
          {topTv.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime key={index} title={item.title} image={item.image_url} />
          ))}
        </TopAni>

        <h2>Top Airing</h2>
        <TopAni>
          {/* {topAiring.length > 0 ? <h2>Top airing</h2> : null} */}
          {topAiring.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime key={index} title={item.title} image={item.image_url} />
          ))}
        </TopAni>

        <h2>Top Upcoming</h2>
        <TopAni>
          {topUpcoming.map((item, index) => (
            <TopAnime key={index} title={item.title} image={item.image_url} />
          ))}
        </TopAni>

      </HomeWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

Comment: After you added the header, what is the raw response of the JSON data?

Comment: @Raptor SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @Dave.Q, Hi, this response is a little late. The is a known issue, it's usually caused by a redirect. You need to set fetch to follow any redirects. `fetch(url, {redirect: 'follow'})` Let me whether that works. You might have to remove `mode: 'no-cors',` as well.